# Combining FluentValidation and IValidatableObject Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

Is it possible to run both FluentValidation **and** IValidatableObject in the same ViewModel? For example if I had the following ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IValidatableObject
{
    public string FooName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FooName))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Required from IValidatableObject", new[] { "FooName" });
        }
    }
}

[Validator(typeof(BarValidator))]
public class Bar
{
    public string BarName { get; set; }
}

public class BarValidator : AbstractValidator<Bar>
{
    public BarValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.BarName).NotNull().WithMessage("Required from FluentValidation");
    }
}
```

Is there a way both `Foo` and `Bar` validations can run and return the results when my Controller calls `ModelState.IsValid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, not currently. See response here: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/545#issuecomment-322757974